# Game getting crashed, global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Tags: c#, uwp, task

I've made a meme game using UWP, but after I changed something is needed, the game is always crashed after 2 cards being choose and takes me to that place at App.g.i.cs:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
```

## endif

I have no idea what causing it, here 's the code behind the buttons:

```
   if (IsFirstOrSecondCard && IsThirdCardChosed == false)
        {
            SecondCardChosen(sender);
        }
        else if (IsThirdCardChosed == false)
        {
            FirstCardChosen(sender);
        }
        else
            ThirdPlusButton();
```

That is spreaded to the whole 16 buttons, the methods:

```
   public async void FirstCardChosen(object sender)
    {
        MemoButton[0] = (Button)sender;

        IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard;

        if (MemoButton[0] == R1C1) { R1C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R1C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R1C1img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R1C2) { R1C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R1C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R1C2img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R1C3) { R1C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R1C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R1C3img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R1C4) { R1C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R1C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R1C4img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R2C1) { R2C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R2C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R2C1img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R2C2) { R2C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R2C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R2C2img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R2C3) { R2C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R2C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R2C3img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R2C4) { R2C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R2C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R2C4img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R3C1) { R3C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R3C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R3C1img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R3C2) { R3C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R3C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R3C2img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R3C3) { R3C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R3C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R3C3img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R3C4) { R3C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R3C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R3C4img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R4C1) { R4C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R4C1img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R4C1img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R4C2) { R4C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R4C2img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R4C2img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R4C3) { R4C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R4C3img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R4C3img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        else if (MemoButton[0] == R4C4) { R4C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(4000, SecondButtonTriggered.Token); R4C4img.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; TempImageLocation[0] = R4C4img; IsFirstOrSecondCard = !IsFirstOrSecondCard; }

        Score.Text = "Score" + Success_Counter.ToString();
    }
```

Second card:

```
     public async void SecondCardChosen(object sender)
    {
        IsFirstOrSecondCard = false;
        IsThirdCardChosed = true;

        Dictionary<Button, string> HiddenCardDiscovery = new Dictionary<Button, string>();

        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R1C1, "OriginalPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R1C2, "PixelPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R1C3, "IronManPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R1C4, "CoolPepe");

        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R2C1, "UrselfPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R2C2, "WinkPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R2C3, "OriginalPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R2C4, "HappyPepe");

        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R3C1, "PixelPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R3C2, "MonsterPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R3C3, "CoolPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R3C4, "IronManPepe");

        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R4C1, "WinkPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R4C2, "UrselfPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R4C3, "MonsterPepe");
        HiddenCardDiscovery.Add(R4C4, "HappyPepe");

        MemoButton[1] = (Button)sender;


        if (MemoButton[1] == R1C1) { TempImageLocation[1] = R1C1img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R1C2) { TempImageLocation[1] = R1C2img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R1C3) { TempImageLocation[1] = R1C3img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R1C4) { TempImageLocation[1] = R1C4img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R2C1) { TempImageLocation[1] = R2C1img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R2C2) { TempImageLocation[1] = R2C2img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R2C3) { TempImageLocation[1] = R2C3img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R2C4) { TempImageLocation[1] = R2C4img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R3C1) { TempImageLocation[1] = R3C1img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R3C2) { TempImageLocation[1] = R3C2img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R3C3) { TempImageLocation[1] = R3C3img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R3C4) { TempImageLocation[1] = R3C4img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R4C1) { TempImageLocation[1] = R4C1img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R4C2) { TempImageLocation[1] = R4C2img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R4C3) { TempImageLocation[1] = R4C3img; }

        else if (MemoButton[1] == R4C4) { TempImageLocation[1] = R4C4img; }


        string FirstButtonImageName = "";
        string SecondButtonImageName = "";

        HiddenCardDiscovery.TryGetValue(MemoButton[0], out FirstButtonImageName);
        HiddenCardDiscovery.TryGetValue(MemoButton[1], out SecondButtonImageName);

        if (FirstButtonImageName == SecondButtonImageName)
        {
            Success_Counter += 1;
            Score.Text = "Score: " + Success_Counter.ToString();
            TempImageLocation[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            TempImageLocation[1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MemoButton[0].IsEnabled = !MemoButton[0].IsEnabled;
            MemoButton[1].IsEnabled = !MemoButton[1].IsEnabled;

            if (Success_Counter == 8)
            {
                Frame.Navigate(typeof(WonPage));
            }             
        }


        else
        {
            TempImageLocation[0].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            TempImageLocation[1].Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(2000);
            TempImageLocation[0].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            TempImageLocation[1].Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        Score.Text = "Score: " + Success_Counter.ToString();
        IsThirdCardChosed = false;
    }
```

And third:

```
  public void ThirdPlusButton ()
    {
        Score.Text = "Please don't press 3 buttons at the same time!"; // Add flyouut box everytime a third button gets clicked at the next update! 
    }
```

And the global varibals:

```
 int Success_Counter = 0;
    Button[] MemoButton = new Button[2];
    bool IsFirstOrSecondCard = false;
    bool IsThirdCardChosed = false;
    Image[] TempImageLocation = new Image[2];
    CancellationTokenSource SecondButtonTriggered = new CancellationTokenSource();
```

Before you comment, things I've tried AND helped: 
At the second method (SecondCardChosen) to set a Delay of 5 seconds before it began like that:

```
public async void SecondCardChosen(object sender)
    {
        IsFirstOrSecondCard = false;
        IsThirdCardChosed = true;
        await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(5000);
```

But if I don't activate a large delay, the game would crash and take me there, tried using google tried looking for a sulotion and I just didn't found any, anyone can plase direct me on the right direction?

EDIT: forgot to add the xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="MemoryGame.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MemoryGame"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="HideableImages">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Fill" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />

    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="QuesionMarkButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE897;"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="72"/>


    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Name="Title" FontSize="36" Text="Memory game by Ido levi" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

    <Button Name="R1C1" BorderThickness ="0,0,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Click="R1C1_Click"     />
    <Button Name="R1C2" BorderThickness="3,0,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Click="R1C2_Click_1" />
    <Button Name="R1C3" BorderThickness="3,0,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Click="R1C3_Click"  />
    <Button Name="R1C4" BorderThickness="3,0,0,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Click="R1C4_Click" />
    <Button Name="R2C1" BorderThickness="0,3,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Click="R2C1_Click" />
    <Button Name="R2C2" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Click="R2C2_Click"/>
    <Button Name="R2C3" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Click="R2C3_Click"/>
    <Button Name="R2C4" BorderThickness="3,3,0,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Click="R2C4_Click" />
    <Button Name="R3C1" BorderThickness="0,3,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Click="R3C1_Click"/>
    <Button Name="R3C2" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Click="R3C2_Click" />
    <Button Name="R3C3" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Click="R3C3_Click" />
    <Button Name="R3C4" BorderThickness="3,3,0,3" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Click="R3C4_Click" />
    <Button Name="R4C1" BorderThickness="0,3,3,0" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Click="R4C1_Click"/>
    <Button Name="R4C2" BorderThickness="3,3,3,0" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Click="R4C2_Click" />
    <Button Name="R4C3" BorderThickness="3,3,3,0" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Click="R4C3_Click"/>
    <Button Name="R4C4" BorderThickness="3,3,0,0" Style="{StaticResource QuesionMarkButton}" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3"  Click="R4C4_Click"/>

    <Image Name="R1C1img"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/OriginalPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R1C2img"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/PixelPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R1C3img"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/IronManPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R1C4img"  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/CoolPepe.jpg"/>

    <Image Name="R2C1img"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/UrselfPepe.png"/>
    <Image Name="R2C2img"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/WinkPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R2C3img"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/OriginalPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R2C4img"  Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/HappyPepe.jpg"/>

    <Image Name="R3C1img"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/PixelPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R3C2img"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/MonsterPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R3C3img"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/CoolPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R3C4img"  Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/IronManPepe.jpg"/>

    <Image Name="R4C1img"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/WinkPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R4C2img"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/UrselfPepe.png"/>
    <Image Name="R4C3img"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/MonsterPepe.jpg"/>
    <Image Name="R4C4img"  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource HideableImages}" Source="Assets/HappyPepe.jpg"/>



    <TextBlock Name="Score" Text="Score:" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="30" />


</Grid>
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a *"Debug my code for me"* service. It's a Q&A site, that works best, when questions come with a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I know that, I don't ask you to debug my code for me, I asked for a directon, I have to idea what is the problem and I'm looking for a direction not solutions, no struggle no learning.

Comment: Set up your debugger to break, when an exception is thrown.

Comment: I tried to show the error at the score.text  for only to start solving that problem, I've wrote this:

Comment: try
            {
                if (IsFirstOrSecondCard && IsThirdCardChosed == false)
                {
                    SecondCardChosen(sender);
                }
                else if (IsThirdCardChosed == false)
                {
                    FirstCardChosen(sender);
                }
                else
                    ThirdPlusButton();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Score.Text = ex.ToString();
            }

But still the same problem

Comment: Your code is a mess. You need a debugger to help you out. Do as I told you in my previous comment. And **don't** ever use try-catch handlers, until you intimately understand exception handling.

Comment: I will admint, I am sort-of a beginer, I'm doing that project only to learn from this, I did learned Try Catch blocks but not how to handel those kind of exceptions, and I have no idea how to build a debugger to break when an exception is thrown, do you mind explaining to me how can I do it or to send me to articles that might could help me please?

Comment: [Managing Exceptions with the Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx).

Comment: Thank you,  I will read that article again tomrrow when I'm more fresh,

Comment: You can put your mouse on the `sender` of `UnhandledException` to see what cause this exception.